# What does it mean to identify a sample space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My homework question asks me to identify a sample space for a given game. I'm confused as to what exactly that means. Should I draw a probability tree, or list all events and their probabilities, or am I completely misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample space is the set of all possible outcomes. This set can range from something simple as a coin toss $(H, T) $ or the roll of a die $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ to much more complicated sets.

For example if you were drawing a group of 20 people from the United States population your sample space would be all possible groups of 20 people from the United States.

Answer (score 2):

The sample space is the set of all possible outcomes - wikipedia:

> In probability theory, the sample space of an experiment or random trial is the set of all possible outcomes or results of that experiment.

So for example, if the event is the outcome of a die roll then the sample space would be {1,2,3,4,5,6}

Comment: What if the game is more complex? It would take a lot of time to list all possible outcomes.

Comment: I guess you can use a range, e.g sum of rolls of a hundred dice: $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq 100$ and $n\leq 600$